# Histogram in R from a csv file with four columns

Tags: r, csv, plot

I have a csv file with four columns AGE, DIASTOLIC, BMI, EVER.PREGNANT. I wish to plot the histogram comparing AGE in x-axis with the DIASTOLIC in the y-axis. How could I do this? The code that I wrote is:

`Sheet=read.csv("/home/prajnan/Downloads/1739230_1284354330_PIMA.csv - 1739230_1284354330_PIMA.csv.csv",sep=",", header = T)`
`hist(Sheet[2],Sheet[3]$AGE$DIASTOLIC)`

The error I get is:

`Error in hist.default(Sheet[2], Sheet[3]$AGE$DIASTOLIC) :'x' must be numeric`
Where is the mistake? Thanks beforehand.

Note:The output for dput(head(Sheet, 10)) is:

```
structure(list(X = c(NA, NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), 
X.1 = structure(c(1L, 53L, 31L, 12L, 13L, 2L, 14L, 11L, 7L, 
34L), .Label = c("", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", 
"27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", 
"37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", 
"47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", 
"57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", 
"67", "68", "69", "70", "81", "AGE"), class = "factor"), 
X.2 = structure(c(1L, 48L, 31L, 28L, 26L, 28L, 13L, 32L, 
17L, 30L), .Label = c("", "100", "102", "104", "106", "108", 
"110", "114", "122", "24", "30", "38", "40", "44", "46", 
"48", "50", "52", "54", "55", "56", "58", "60", "61", "62", 
"64", "65", "66", "68", "70", "72", "74", "75", "76", "78", 
"80", "82", "84", "85", "86", "88", "90", "92", "94", "95", 
"96", "98", "DIASTOLIC"), class = "factor"), X.3 = structure(c(1L, 
248L, 124L, 63L, 31L, 78L, 210L, 54L, 104L, 100L), .Label = c("", 
"18.2", "18.4", "19.1", "19.3", "19.4", "19.5", "19.6", "19.9", 
"20", "20.1", "20.4", "20.8", "21", "21.1", "21.2", "21.7", 
"21.8", "21.9", "22.1", "22.2", "22.3", "22.4", "22.5", "22.6", 
"22.7", "22.9", "23", "23.1", "23.2", "23.3", "23.4", "23.5", 
"23.6", "23.7", "23.8", "23.9", "24", "24.1", "24.2", "24.3", 
"24.4", "24.5", "24.6", "24.7", "24.8", "24.9", "25", "25.1", 
"25.2", "25.3", "25.4", "25.5", "25.6", "25.8", "25.9", "26", 
"26.1", "26.2", "26.3", "26.4", "26.5", "26.6", "26.7", "26.8", 
"26.9", "27", "27.1", "27.2", "27.3", "27.4", "27.5", "27.6", 
"27.7", "27.8", "27.9", "28", "28.1", "28.2", "28.3", "28.4", 
"28.5", "28.6", "28.7", "28.8", "28.9", "29", "29.2", "29.3", 
"29.5", "29.6", "29.7", "29.8", "29.9", "30", "30.1", "30.2", 
"30.3", "30.4", "30.5", "30.7", "30.8", "30.9", "31", "31.1", 
"31.2", "31.3", "31.6", "31.9", "32", "32.1", "32.2", "32.3", 
"32.4", "32.5", "32.6", "32.7", "32.8", "32.9", "33.1", "33.2", 
"33.3", "33.5", "33.6", "33.7", "33.8", "33.9", "34", "34.1", 
"34.2", "34.3", "34.4", "34.5", "34.6", "34.7", "34.8", "34.9", 
"35", "35.1", "35.2", "35.3", "35.4", "35.5", "35.6", "35.7", 
"35.8", "35.9", "36", "36.1", "36.2", "36.3", "36.4", "36.5", 
"36.6", "36.7", "36.8", "36.9", "37", "37.1", "37.2", "37.3", 
"37.4", "37.5", "37.6", "37.7", "37.8", "37.9", "38", "38.1", 
"38.2", "38.3", "38.4", "38.5", "38.6", "38.7", "38.8", "38.9", 
"39", "39.1", "39.2", "39.3", "39.4", "39.5", "39.6", "39.7", 
"39.8", "39.9", "40", "40.1", "40.2", "40.5", "40.6", "40.7", 
"40.8", "40.9", "41", "41.2", "41.3", "41.5", "41.8", "42", 
"42.1", "42.2", "42.3", "42.4", "42.6", "42.7", "42.8", "42.9", 
"43.1", "43.3", "43.4", "43.5", "43.6", "44", "44.1", "44.2", 
"44.5", "44.6", "45", "45.2", "45.3", "45.4", "45.5", "45.6", 
"45.7", "45.8", "46.1", "46.2", "46.3", "46.5", "46.7", "46.8", 
"47.9", "48.3", "48.8", "49.3", "49.6", "49.7", "50", "52.3", 
"52.9", "53.2", "55", "57.3", "59.4", "67.1", "BMI"), class = "factor"), 
X.4 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("", 
"EVER-PREGNANT", "\"no\"", "\"yes\""), class = "factor")), .Names = c("X",
```

"X.1", "X.2", "X.3", "X.4"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a histogram is a graph showing the frequency of values in a single distribution. You can not use it to compare two values. To look at a single distribution within your dataset you could do something like this:

```
hist(sheet$AGE)
```

and likewise:

```
hist(sheet$DIASTOLIC)
```

if you wanted them to be plotted together to compare the two distributions you could do this:

```
par(mfrow = c(2, 1))
hist(sheet$AGE)
hist(sheet$DIASTOLIC)
```

If, however, you are looking to compare the two variables directly, a histogram is likely not what you want. You could start by doing a simple scatter plot like this:

```
plot(sheet$AGE, sheet$DIASTOLIC)
```

Comment: When I type `hist(Sheet$AGE)`, I get the error; 'x' must be numeric, how should I proceed?

Comment: if I had to guess, I would guess that the column was read in as a factor rather than numeric. try `hist(as.numeric(Sheet$AGE))` I would be able to say for sure if you paste the output of `dput(Sheet)` into your question

Comment: tried `hist(as.numeric(Sheet$AGE))` with output as Error in hist.default(as.numeric(Sheet$AGE)) : invalid number of 'breaks'. The `dput(Sheet)` output is so long that to indent it as a code reqires some time. Shall I send a picture instead?

Comment: no. a picture won't help. do `dput(head(Sheet, 10))`

Comment: are the desired column names in the first row of the csv file? Your problem is that your column names are actually `X.1`, `X.2`, etc. and your desired column names are in the second row. This is why the data will not graph

Comment: looking at the csv files, I find that the column names are in the first row. But when I do `colnames(Sheet)`, I find the column names to be "X.1,X.2,X.3,X.4". How do I rectify this?

Comment: I am not entirely sure, if I had to guess, it could have something to do with your file name `"/home/prajnan/Downloads/1739230_1284354330_PIMA.csv - 1739230_1284354330_PIMA.csv.csv"`. I am not 100% sure, but the 3 `.csv` seem like it would be a problem

Comment: thanks, solved the problem! Changed the name of file